# How to check if column has valid values or not?

Tags: r

I need to derive a column from existing column after checking if it has valid entry not .
INPUT

```
   ID
    2

    4
    6


    34
```

Output

```
ID  ID_ENTRY
2   PRESENT
    NOT PRESENT
4   PRESENT
6   PRESENT
    NOT PRESENT
    NOT PRESENT
34  PRESENT
```

Comment: Are those empty text strings or numerics? In R you'd get NA if it's a numeric vector. Then you'd just need to do `ifelse(!is.na(ID), "PRESENT", "NOT PRESENT")`

Comment: have you tried any code from your end?

Comment: gsub(" ",' Not Present ',ID)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A base R option here would be to use `ifelse`:

```
df$ID_ENTRY <- ifelse(ID != "", "PRESENT", "NOT PRESENT")
```

If you could have empty string, null, or NA missing values then we can use:

```
df$ID_ENTRY <- ifelse(ID != "" & !is.na(ID) & !is.null(ID),
                      "PRESENT", "NOT PRESENT")
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually, this is can be solved with `is.na`:

```
dat[,"ID_ENTRY"] <- ifelse(is.na(dat[,"ID"]), "NOT PRESENT", "PRESENT")
```

However, sometimes it is necessary to check the type of the column in question and use different approach in this case. For instance, if it a `character` column, the approach would be

```
dat[, "ID_ENTRY"] <- ifelse(dat[,"ID"]=="", "NOT PRESENT", "PRESENT")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use can use [`sapply`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/lapply.html).

```
vec1 <- c("a", "b", "c", "")
vec2 <- sapply(vec1, function(x){ifelse(x == "", "NOT PRESENT", "PRESENT")})
vec2
## "PRESENT"     "PRESENT"     "PRESENT" "NOT PRESENT"
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that ID is a `factor`

```
   ss <- data.frame(ID = c(2,' ',4,6,' ',' ',34))

 > ss$ID_ENTRY <- lapply(ss$ID,function(x){ifelse(is.na(as.numeric(as.character(x))),'NOTPRESENT','PRESENT')})
> ss
  ID   ID_ENTRY
1  2    PRESENT
2    NOTPRESENT
3  4    PRESENT
4  6    PRESENT
5    NOTPRESENT
6    NOTPRESENT
7 34    PRESENT
>
```